# ajax demo for laravel, step by step

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I think this code has a lot of errors. What i need is to create a form, do a XHR submit to the controller, get the data, send to model, check the validations, return to controller with the output of validation and then sent to the view the message "errors or success"

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('checkValidationEmail', 'HomeController@checkValidationEmail');
```

---

```
<?php
echo Form::open(array('url' => 'checkValidationEmail', 'class' => 'form_notify'));
echo Form::text('Email', Input::old('Email'),  array('placeholder'=>'Email', 'class' => 'hg'));
echo Form::close() 
?>

<a href="#" class="send_email"> Notify Me!</a>
```

ok, this works fine, next, the problems begin.

---

AJAX

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".send_email").click(function () {
            email = $('.hg').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'checkValidationEmail', //what is the correct url?
                data: {
                    email: email
                }
            }).done(function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

500 error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException","message":"","file":"C:\\VertrigoServ\\www\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php","line":1439}}
```

---

**Controller**

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
       public function checkValidationEmail() {
           //how to get the data from form and pass to the model, more exactly validate($input)

                   if ($validation) {
                      return true;  
                   }
                   else {
                      return 'incorrect email'; //how send this message to the view?
                   }
       }
}
```

---

**Model**

```
class Home extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'emails';

    public function validate($input) {
       //validations
    }

}
```

Comment: So what are the problems?

Comment: @GladToHelp, basically, the first starts with a nice error 500 in $.ajax.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to set up the correct route in Laravel. One of them is: $url = URL::to('checkValidationEmail');
You might want to check the documentation first:
 http://laravel.com/docs/routing   . As for getting the data on the server side, you can do that by: $input = Input::get('email');.

Comment: @GladToHelp Do you mean url: '<?php echo URL::to('checkValidationEmail') ?>', ?  this give me the same error.

Comment: You are trying to make a POST request while in your routes.php you have defined a route that allows only GET requests. You can either change that to Route::post('checkValidationEmail', 'HomeController@checkValidationEmail'); or to Route::any('checkValidationEmail', 'HomeController@checkValidationEmail');

Comment: To make things easy on yourself, try naming your route with `Route::post('checkValidationEmail', array('uses' => 'HomeController@checkValidationEmail', 'as' => 'ajax.checkValidationEmail'));` Then in your javascript, `url: '{{ URL::route('ajax.checkValidationEmail') }}', //what is the correct url?`

Comment: Check your ajax URL parameter. it may be wrong. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157215/laravel-4-ajax-not-working

Answer (score 5):

In your route you are defined the `checkValidationEmail` as `GET` request and from your ajax, you are trying to access this as a `POST` request. So this will throw `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. So you have to change your route from,

```
Route::get('checkValidationEmail', 'HomeController@checkValidationEmail');
```

To,

```
Route::post('checkValidationEmail', 'HomeController@checkValidationEmail');
```

Or,

```
Route::any('checkValidationEmail', 'HomeController@checkValidationEmail');
```