# Laravel 4 + AJAX not working

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I am very new to Laravel 4 and I'm trying to test AJAX request.

In my `script.js` I have this:

```
(function() {
  $("#login-submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "laravel/ajax/login", //i put my public in "localhost/laravel/public/"
      cache: false,
      data: 'email:' + $("#email").val(),
      success: function(data) {
        return alert(data);
      },
      error: function(response) {
        return alert("ERROR:" + response.responseText);
      }
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

That is called from this html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <input type="text" id="email" />

        <label for="email">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" id="password" />

        <button id="login-submit">Log In</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery/jquery.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Controller class:

```
class AuthController extends BaseController
{
    public function login()
    {
        echo 'success';
    }
}
```

And router:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return View::make('homepage');
});

Route::post('/ajax/login', 'AuthController@login');
```

By clicking `Log In` it should be echoing "success" but instead it throws this error:

```
ERROR:{
    "error": {
        "type": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
        "message": "",
        "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
        "line":1429
    }
}
```

What's wrong in this?

Comment: After solving the url problem does the controller function login echo success..???

Comment: @John: it does, already been solved, thanks for answering

Comment: Are you tried with ajax login with validation errors. Refer this article http://wsnippets.com/create-ajax-login-laravel-4/ is good one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the AJAX call, change:

```
  url: "laravel/ajax/login",
```

To:

```
  url: "ajax/login",
```

Your route is listening to `ajax/login`, **not** `laravel/ajax/login`.

Read more about routes [here](http://laravel.com/docs/routing).

Comment: yeah it works now, there's another problem now actually, thanks for answering

Comment: @user2002495 You can always submit it here, we'll be glad to help.

Comment: May I know who down voted my question - even though it solved the problem?

Comment: I upvoted it again, I don't know about the down vote, weird for any1 who down vote it